# Apache2 403 Forbidden in custom document root

Tags: apache, ubuntu, webserver, http-status-code-403, document-root

I have searched anything on this topic in the internet and i just cannot get it to work. I am desperate....

I just want to access my index.php inside a custom document root folder but i keep getting this error

[image]

The new document root that i want instead of the /var/www/html default is called

```
/home/ever/FH/SKS/frontend
```

I have set all the permission recursively to 775 for this folder and all subfolders.

[image]

The main apache configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf looks like this:

[image]

Most instructions i have found on how to set a new directory root, told me to just change the path inside the /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file to point to my new document root.

My 000-default.conf:

[image]

I also tried a version of the 000-default.conf file that looked like this:

[image]

The symlinks should be corrrect:

[image]

I have not set up any .htaccess file or changed anythign else.

Please help me... i am desperate. In XAMPP this is done super easy, but i refuse that this cannot be done with the normal Apache server too. It cant be THAT big of a deal can it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in version 2.4 of the apache webserver i have to use

```
<Directory /var/www/foo>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

instead of 2.2 syntax

```
<Directory /var/www/example.com>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

furthermore i have to place the configuration inside the

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

file instead of the

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

file.

My apache2.conf now looks like this:

[image]

allowing me to finally access the file WITHOUT PHP  support it seems....

but this is another long complicated battle that never happened before with XAMPP i guess.....

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.

Comment: for me, in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, i simply changed <Directory /var/www/> to <Directory /new/location/>, restarted the apache2 service, and it worked.